# how to jump to another page in Google Apps Script site

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I would like to give a page transition.

In web server (Google side), I prepare an html file like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<h1>Moving</h1>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://google.com">link</a>
<script> window.location.href='https://google.com'</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that using the link `link`, I can jump to the google page (`google.com`).

However I got a console message like below and cannot jump automatically with Javascript...

```
Refused to display 'https://google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I think this is a limitation in Google Apps Script..
Is there anyway to let users jump without clicking the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were able to do it with `window.top.location.href`.

However, it seems it has been just blocked by Chrome CORS since this month.